# Knockoutjs binding after user clicks link

Tags: knockout.js

I'm new to javascript/jquery and am learning knockoutjs. I am stuck on this problem. I have two ko binds in my page. The first one creates a link that users would click on in order to view more information about that item. That link contains an ID that is passed to an ajax call, which returns data to the second ko observable.

The problem is that the second observable data is always showing up as 'undefined' on the page. Yet, if I put a console.log(data) in the code where the observable is created, the data is there. Likewise, in Fiddler the json requested by ajax call is being sent back fine.

I'm sure this is something to do with how I am binding the observables, but I have tried several different ways (with array, without array, etc.) and to no avail. Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated. Seems like a simple problem, but I've tried everything and can't get it to work...

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var da = new firstViewModel();

        ko.applyBindings(da, document.getElementById('da'));


        var eq = new secondViewModel(); 
//Binding the second observable here but not using it yet as it depends on getting data from the //first (da) in order to work.

        ko.applyBindings(eq, document.getElementById('eqdetails'));  

    });

     function da(data) {
            var self = this;
            self.eqid = ko.observable(data.eqid);
            self.modelname = ko.observable(data.modelname);

        }

    function firstViewModel() {

        // Data    
        var self = this;
    self.da = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.getdetails = function (da) {

        selectedid = da.eqid();

//Call second observable when user clicks on link. 
        var eq = new secondViewModel();
        eq.geteqdetails();

    }

    };
};


     function eqview(data) {

        console.log('in eqview ' + data); //This works, but data is still undefined in html 
        var self = this;
        self.modelname = ko.observable(data.modelname);
        self.number = ko.observable(data.number);

    };

    function secondViewModel() {

        var self = this;

        self.eqviews = ko.observableArray([]);

        self.geteqdetails = function () {

            $.ajax("../Process/GetEqDetails", {
                type: "post",
                contentType: "application/json",
                data: JSON.stringify({ EqID: selectedid }),
                success: function (result) {
                    console.log('in ajax call ' + result.data);

                    var mappedequipmentview = $.map(result, function (item) { return new eqview(item) });
                    self.eqviews(mappedequipmentview);

                }
            });

        };
```

Here is the HTML of the page:

```
<div id="da" class="span3">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Model</th>
                <th>ID</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="template: { name: 'datemplate', foreach: da }">
        </tbody>
    </table>


    <script id="datemplate" type="text/html">
        <tr>
            <td><span data-bind="text: modelname"></span></td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" data-bind="click: $root.getdetails" title="View">
                    <span data-bind="text: eqid"></span></button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </script>
</div>


<div class="span6">

    <div class="span1">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed"  id="eqdetails">
        <tbody >

            <tr>
                <td><span data-bind="text: $data.modelname "></span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><span data-bind="text: $data.number "></span></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>


    </div>



    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: here's an untested theory... using `new secondViewModel()` will generate a new instance of secondViewModel, but it will never replace the one you're already binding. what happens when you put `ko.applyBindings(eq, document.getElementById('eqdetails'));` underneath the statement `var eq = new secondViewModel();` in `firstViewModel`?

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work. I get the same issue, where the 'console.log' within the 'eqview function' works, but on the page I get 'undefined'. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are several errors in the code you show.

- You're instantiating a "secondViewModel" once document is ready, and you apply bindings on it. That's fine, but you never use it: you're instantiating a new model on line 33 of your code. You should not do that. Once you have applied bindings for a model, you have to keep a reference to this model if you want to change data in it. Knockout is kind of magical, but not that much: it does not know that it has to bind each secondViewModel that you create to the "eqdetails" table.
- On line 62 of your code, your referencing a "selectid" variable, which does not exist in the context of your "geteqdetails" function. You should pass "selectid" as a parameter to the "geteqdetails" function to be able to reference it.
- Finally, I am not sure that your need two view models. I think that makes your code harder to understand and to maintain. I would probably use only one view model. This way, you would not have to keep a reference to the secondViewModel to update its data. Or, another way would be to use routing.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I implemented points 1 & 2 and these did help, but did not fix the issue of the second view model being undefined on the page (though the data is there). I was intrigued by point #3, but was not able to figure out a good way to combine the two. As all attempts to get the two view models working were not successful, I decided to use only one, and then just use jquery to pull in the details after a user clicks. Thank you for your comments.

Comment: Could you post a jsfiddle showing your solution? I am not sure that using jQuery is the best solution.

Comment: Here is a posting: [http://jsfiddle.net/v5Med/](http://jsfiddle.net/v5Med/) Please let me know if this gives enough info. Thanks!